# Redirect/call method from another controller in a different namespace in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, devise, cancancan

I have a pretty typical situation where I have a `'/dashboard'` which should render a different view for different user roles (i.e. client, admin, etc.).

I am open to more elegant suggestions but my thought was to have one route definition for dashboard like so:

**routes.rb**

```
resource :dashboard
```

and to have a **dashboards_controller.rb** like so:

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    if current_user.has_role?('sysadmin')
      // show system admin dashboard
    elsif
      // show a different dashboard

    // etc
    end
  end
end
```

Now I would like that each dashboard gets built in its role specific namespaced dashboard_controller, ex: `controllers/admin/dashboard_controller.rb`. This way, each dashboard can be appropriately built up in the right place.

The way I am trying to do this is to redirect from my main `dashboards_controller` to the `admin/dashboard_controller` like so:

```
redirect_to :controller => 'admin/dashboard_controller', :action => 'index'
```

But it is not working, presumably because I am not sure how to reference a namespaced controller from here.

How can I achieve this?

(If there is a more elegant solution I am open but I thought this was pretty good).

I am using devise and cancancan.

Comment: Could you post your full routes? Especially the namespaced controller?

Comment: @waza that's the only relevant route

Answer (score 2):

You can do per-role dashboard, for example:

**routes.rb**

```
scope '/:role' do
  resources :dashboard
end

resources :dashboard
```

Then to redirect with the role, just simply:

```
redirect_to :controller => 'dashboard', :action => 'index', :role => 'admin'
```

---

## The Better Way

If you want custom dispatch per controller, you should consider using filter. E.g. given `admin/dashboard` only accessible by admin and `user/dashboard` only accessible by default user, you may want to create files like this:

**routes.rb**

```
namespace 'admin' do
  resources :dashboard
end

namespace 'user' do
  resources :dashboard
end
```

Then you create these files:

```
app/controllers/admin/dashboards_controller.rb
app/controllers/admin/admin_base_controller.rb
app/controllers/user/dashboards_controller.rb
app/controllers/user/user_base_controller.rb
```

For each files:

```
# app/controllers/admin/dashboards_controller.rb
class Admin::DashboardsController < Admin::AdminBaseController; end

# app/controllers/admin/admin_base_controller.rb
class Admin::AdminBaseController < ApplicationController
  before_action :ensure_admin!

  def ensure_admin!
    redirect_to controller: 'user/dashboards', action: index unless current_user.has_role?('sysadmin')
  end
end

# Now you've got the idea. Similar things for the rest of the files:
# app/controllers/user/dashboards_controller.rb
# app/controllers/user/user_base_controller.rb
```

Then you can try visiting it at `admin/dashboards` and `user/dashboards`, it should be redirected to its role accordingly.

Comment: Wops, mistakenly understand your question. Is it working now?

Comment: ah right that 'better way' makes a lot of sense. my only question is, let's say in my code i want my controllers and views to be namespaced for organization, but I don't want the end user to go to `'/admin/dashboard'` or `'/user/dashboard'` it would be better if everyone went to `'/dashboard'` and got sent the proper view... that is why I was trying with this redirect business

Comment: Got it. So you have two different views but you only want 1 controller to handle that? Or, it is fine to have two controllers for each user, but you want a simple single route for each role? (`/dashboard` instead of multiple `/:role/dashboard`)

Comment: i want a simple single route (`/dashboard`) which is handled by different controllers (and then different views). and I would prefer to not have this logic in my routes file. (I could have done it with constraints in the routes file, but I would rather keep the routes clean i think)

Comment: You may want to try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476234/rails-sti-single-path-different-controller). It is pretty challenging to dispatch multiple controller with single route.

Answer (score 1):

It's good to use named route helpers rather than providing controller and action explicitly.

Consider adding routes as follows:

```
namespace :admin do
  resource :dashboard, controller: 'dashboard '
end
```

Then you can call :

```
redirect_to admin_dashboard_url
```

Remember, it's resource, not resources. So it is going to process dashboard_controller#show, not dashboard_controller#index

Comment: i could do that but I was trying to avoid having so much going on in my routes file. As of now I have 5 different roles, and I would rather not have to add five different declarations in my routes file. I would rather have one route declaration, and then hide that logic somewhere else. (though, I am very new to rails - coming from laravel, so I don't really know best practices yet)